# Upload video directly to Google+ Photos via Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, picasa

I can upload a video to Google Drive with the Google Drive API, but storage is limited.

Now, I want to upload unlimited video to Google Photos directly using the Google Drive API.

I found the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code), but I can't download the PHP library because I get a "page 404 not found" error.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you had a look at this [Wrapper library](https://github.com/Camalot9/Lightweight-PHP-Picasa-API) instead?

Comment: No. Do you read this question clearly, @matov ? <br> my mean : can i upload directly to google+ photo by google drive api, do not directly upload to google drive, right!

Comment: Thanks @AL. , but it may be expired and website does not support anymore :(